# Why isn't this align environment aligning?

Tags: support, mathjax

Lately I haven't been able to get the "align" environment to work properly, except on trivial examples.  It was always a little finicky, but in the last few days it seems to have gotten much worse.

This isn't formatting properly on Firefox 23.  (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0)

$$\begin{align}
\color{green}{\exists \;x \in D \; : P(x) & = \exists \;x \in D \; \; ( \;x \in A 
\wedge P(x) \;) \tag{E = Existential}}
\end{align}$$

Here's a screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

Am I making some mistake that would be easy to fix?

[ Update: Asaf points out that the alignment tab symbol `&` is embedded inside the `\green` block, so that the constructions on either side have unbalanced braces.  Changing

> ```
>  \color{green}{… & …}
> ```

to

> ```
>  \color{green}{…} & \color{green}{…}
> ```

fixes the problem:

$$\begin{align}
\color{green}{\exists \;x \in D \; : P(x)} & = \color{green}{\exists \;x \in D \; \; ( \;x \in A 
\wedge P(x) \;) \tag{E = Existential}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `\color` bit outside the `align` bit. It will work just fine.

$$
\color{green}{
\begin{align}\exists \;x \in D \; : P(x) & = \exists \;x \in D \; \; ( \;x \in A 
\wedge P(x) \;) \tag{E = Existential}
\end{align}}$$

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$